# Pages question on Apple yosemite

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

How can I get rid of the Right hand column (with Margin, layout info) on 
the Pages. I just want the page to show my letter when sending.

I run Pages v5 on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 2):

On the upperright, click on the selected tab (probably the layout tab is selected) to make it go away